# .htaccess rewriting with conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am stuck with rewrites.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)?$ index.php?p=$1&key=$2
```

The above should match

```
mydomain.com/page
mydomain.com/page/
mydomain.com/page/key
mydomain.com/page/key/
```

but for some cases, I need to match `/specific_page_here/url`/ which would be rewritten to `index.php?p=$1&url=$2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One isssue I believe is that you have a '-' that's not accepted. The regex should be [a-zA-Z0-9-_]

If you want to match a specific page, simply do that exact text:

```
RewriteRule ^my_page/([a-zA-Z0-9\?=&\/\.:\-_@;%]+)$ index.php?p=specific&url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work in this case:

http://localhost/my_page/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid

Also, url may be a vimeo url or any other url on the internet.

Comment: I see. I edited it so urls like that would work. I'm not sure if that's all url types, though.

Comment: It seems only things before ? are matched: https:/www.youtube.com/watch

Comment: Hmm, I thought that might be the case. It's assuming those are variables for whatever page you're requesting, so parses them for you. The good news is that you should still be able to see those arguments. Try printing out the arguments in index.php to see. The other solution is to encode the url before calling that page.